# JPA create query by method name - order by NULL last

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Student.java

```
UUID id;
int age;
int rank;
```

StudentRepository.java

```
List<Student> findAllOrderByRankAscAgeDesc();
```

This repository method returns nulls first (if students has the same rank, the one who has the null age orders first). I'm trying to find a way to implement where null values comes last. Is there any way to do it?

A solution:
Using spesification:

```
q.orderBy(cb.asc(cb.coalesce(s.get("rank"), Float.MAX_VALUE)), cb.desc(cb.coalesce(s.get("age"), Float.MIN_VALUE)));
```

by doing this I  can get the solution I want but I rather use the JPA's query methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try this property
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_by.default_null_ordering=last